# Android contact: why need to requery each time use Contacts Phone List

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contactscontract

Each many examples (website, tutorial, ebook...), when we need to see Phone number of one contact ID, we need to requery like below code:

```
Cursor contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);         
if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()){
            id = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        }
        contactCursor.close();

        //CHOOSE MOBILE PHONE OF CONTACT_ID
        Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                                        new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
                                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + id + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE+ "=" +ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE ,
                                                        null, null);
```

But, If I query directly at `one contact uri` and filter column _ID = contactID. I will meet error at query. Here my code:

```
String[] projector = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
        String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "=" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;
        Cursor phoneContact = getContentResolver().query(uri, projector, selection, null, null);
```

Notes: uri object in above code return when someone choose one contact from contact list.

@Edit: here my error I receive:
Here my error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r2-354F574135474F2741334D352743/2
>   flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.basic/com.data.SMSContactApp}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1

Thanks :)

Comment: @zapl I have added my error. I don't think it's sql grammar error. Please watch it for me. thanks :)

Comment: "data1" (=`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER`) does not exist in the database when you query with this Uri. You might need to use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` as Uri

Comment: @zapl Oh, as you say, so in table of  each `uri` contact doesn't contain Phone Number column ? Can you tell me what columns this table contains, please. I google but no result for my query  Thanks :)

Comment: You can print out the columns or try to find that in the API docs. `Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);String[] names = c.getColumnNames();for (String name : names)  Log.d("lala", "column:" + name); c.close();`